# WebRequest.Create throws System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-3.5

I am trying to create the instance of `WebRequest` but it throws the exception.

Code:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("somURL");
```

Error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

This code is working on local environment but failed on client production server.

Note: client has recently change the hosting. .Net Framework is 3.5.

**Full Exception:**

```
System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed. at System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) at System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() at System.Net.HttpWebRequest..ctor(Uri uri, ServicePoint servicePoint) at System.Net.HttpRequestCreator.Create(Uri Uri) at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Uri requestUri, Boolean useUriBase) at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(String requestUriString) at
```

Comment: Yes. at this line.

Comment: Please post the full exception, including its call stack, not just the message. You can get the full exception with `Exception.ToString`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, you gave nice hint

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the exception, it look like the Code Access Security has raise this. I see a similar thread, please take a look.

[Security Exception of WebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902922/webrequest-create-causing-securityexception-in-a-net-3-5-class-lib-but-not-in)

[About Code Access Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: I yet not tried, but by adding the <trust level="Full" /> under <system.web>, issue gets resolved. Anyways, thanks.